# Straight lines - equation of line

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
A line $4x + y = 1$ through the point A(2, -7) meets the line BC whose equation is $3x - 4y + 1 = 0$ at point B. Find the equation to the line AC, so that AB = AC.

I can't even understand what the question is exactly asking. A small hint to get me started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Still working on it?

Comment: @mistermarko Sorry went on a short trip.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a diagram, which is always useful.

Now follow Adriano's steps.

Answer (score 0):

It's mapping out a triangle. First, assume that the first line just goes through A. We know that it meets BC at the B end. The other end is C, which can be connected to A by AC. Then we have a triangle so mentally cut off the bit of AB outside the triangle. We need to find the line equation for the side we don't have it for. As for the equality - need to think more about that.

Only one corner of the triangle is specified so, presumably, we can make it the right size to ensure that AB = AC. How to do that I leave to you.

Looking at Rainier's diagram we can ask if it can be done without drawing. First, translate A to (0,0), then starting with an equation for AC identical to AB we can vary the slope by leaving it as an unknown. The equations for AC and BC can now be treated as simultaneous with an unknown intersection. Since the slope of AC is also unknown we may have one unknown too many. If this could be solved we would then have to reverse the translation.

Another thought: ABC is equilateral. The angle between AB and AC is therefore 180 - 2*[angle AB BC]. This gives us the slope of AC, which should be enough to solve the simultaneous equations. Considering this you may not need to do the translation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of what you need to do:

- Sketch point $A$ as well the two intersecting lines.
- Solve the system of two linear equations to find $B$, the point of intersection.
- Compute the distance between $A$ and $B$ using Pythagoras, and call this number $r$.
- Draw a circle centred at $A$ with radius $r$. Notice that it will intersect line $BC$ twice; we want to find $C$, the second intersection point. This guarantees that $AB = r = AC$.
- Find the equation of the circle you just drew.
- Solve the system consisting of this circle and the line $BC$ in to order to get $C$.
- Find the slope between $A$ and $C$.
- Use the point-slope formula to get the equation of line $AC$.

Answer (score 0):

To find equation of line $\overline{AC}$ you need to know what $A$ and $C$ are..

You already know what $A$ is... You want to know what $C$ is..

It is given that $AB=AC$.. To use this you need to know what $B$ is..

It is given that $B$ is point of intersection of those two lines..

So, Now you got what $B$ is...

Use $AB=AC$ condition for $C=(x,y)$... You will get a circle..

Can you guess how to get  $C$..